# Type mismatch: expected type parameter `N`, found struct `Vec<u8>`

Tags: rust, types

I summarised my Rust code as followed:

```rust
struct Answer<N> {
    ans: N
}

trait Trait {
    fn func1<N: AsRef<[u8]>>(&self, param1: &[N]) -> Answer<N>;
}

struct MyStruct {}

impl Trait for MyStruct {
    fn func1<N: AsRef<[u8]>>(&self, param1: &[N]) -> Answer<N> {
        
        // This way we prevent bounding additional `Clone` trait on N,
        //   and not do `let ans = param1[0].clone()`
        let ans_ref: &[u8] = param1[0].as_ref();
        let mut ans: Vec<u8> = vec![0; ans_ref.len()];
        ans[..].clone_from_slice(ans_ref);
        
        Answer { ans }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=675725d67ce9eda92d78cd625a16eee5)

It returns error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:18
   |
12 |     fn func1<N: AsRef<[u8]>>(&self, param1: &[N]) -> Answer<N> {
   |              - this type parameter
...
20 |         Answer { ans }
   |                  ^^^ expected type parameter `N`, found struct `Vec`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `N`
                      found struct `Vec<u8>`
```

My question is if I do have `Vec<u8>` after some processing inside `func1`, is there any way to "typecast" `Vec<u8>` back to `N: AsRef<[u8]>`, as `Vec<u8>` implements `AsRef<[u8]>`?

Thanks.

Comment: There is not much sense to your code, please explain why you want this, what are you trying here ? mostly that what you look its look want https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae4fe577ccbc480af672ddc8297c3d0c

Comment: I intentionally renamed and struct / types and simplified the code to show only what is causing a compiler error. But my intent is clear. Inside a function if I get a Vec<u8>, and returning a struct with generic type N: AsRef<[u8]>, and `Vec<u8>` is "kind of N", why can't I return it this way?

Comment: @Stargateur that's the whole point of this person's question. You could just explain why that doesn't make sense, just saying "it doesn't make sense" doesn't help anyone. The question makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are saying "I want param1 to be a slice of `N`". Someone can pass `&[String::from("whatever")]` to `func1` and then `N` will be of type `String`. Your return type is `Answer<N>` so in this case `N` should be a `String` but you are trying to return a `Vec<u8>`. The caller is able to choose the type of `N` so you can't just return any other type. So to answer your direct question, it's not possible to do this.

In this case to make it work you can change `Answer`'s `ans` field to be `Box<dyn AsRef<[u8]>>`, for example:

```rust
struct Answer {
    ans: Box<dyn AsRef<[u8]>>,
} 

trait Trait {
    fn func1<N: AsRef<[u8]>>(&self, param1: &[N]) -> Answer;
}

struct MyStruct {}

impl Trait for MyStruct {
    fn func1<N: AsRef<[u8]>>(&self, param1: &[N]) -> Answer {
        // This way we prevent bounding additional `Clone` trait on N,
        //   and not do `let ans = param1[0].clone()`
        let ans_ref: &[u8] = param1[0].as_ref();
        let mut ans: Vec<u8> = vec![0; ans_ref.len()];
        ans[..].clone_from_slice(ans_ref);
        Answer { ans: Box::new(ans) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // we can pass a Vec of String, as String has an AsRef<[u8]> impl
    let params = vec![String::from("test")];
    let my_struct = MyStruct {};
    my_struct.func1(&params);

    // we can also pass a Vec of Vec
    let params = vec![vec![1, 2, 3, 4]];
    let my_struct = MyStruct {};
    my_struct.func1(&params);
}
```

Comment: I study further about your solution. Just realize now for `ans`, `Box` is like a pointer, and `dyn AsRef<u8>` is another level of pointer. So ans is a pointer to pointer.

To retrieve the value out from Answer, I need to do `my_ans.ans.as_ref().as_ref()`. But this indeed answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

@wayofthepie, @Stargateur (saw your suggestion in the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae4fe577ccbc480af672ddc8297c3d0c)) thanks for both the suggestions; and @wayofthepie thanks for understanding my question.

Eventually my colleague also offers an alternative solution which I think is simpler.

```rust
struct Answer<N> {
    ans: N,
}

trait Trait {
    fn func1<N: AsRef<[u8]> + From<Vec<u8>>>(param1: &[N]) -> Answer<N>;
}

struct MyStruct {}

impl Trait for MyStruct {
    fn func1<N: AsRef<[u8]> + From<Vec<u8>>>(param1: &[N]) -> Answer<N> {
        // some computation here and get the desired ans in vector of byte.
        let ans: Vec<u8> = b"abc".to_vec();
        Answer { ans: ans.into() }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Adding a `From<Vec<u8>>` trait bound here. Eventually `ans` inside Answer needs to be in the type of `N`, not `Vec<u8>`, so we need to convert it to `N`.